# Error Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am so frustrated that i probably wont be able to explain well, but basically im trying to code a music app player however whenever i click the button the app just crashes. The Logcat doesnt really help much since i dont know whats wrong with it. Please help me out T.T

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Proceeding to login page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            openLogIn();


        }
    });

}

public void openLogIn(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/musicAppTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
    android:text="@string/apollotunes"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/millions_of_songs_to_choose_from_n_with_no_interruptions"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/musicAppTitle"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/project_logo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
    android:text="@string/let_s_get_started"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textStart" />
```

Login.java:
"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    TextView password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

    Button loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInButton);

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(email.getText().toString().equals("flanders070105@gmail.com") && password.getText().toString().equals("2202231C"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "LOGIN FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}"

activity_login.xml:
"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/signInText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
    android:text="Sign into your account!"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signInText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
    tools:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logInButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="153dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="164dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />
```

error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalapollotunes/com.example.finalapollotunes.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.example.finalapollotunes.Login.onCreate(Login.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f0501a5
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0501a5
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:255)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:785)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:897)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
enter cE/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:659)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:655)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:651)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:587)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.example.finalapollotunes.Login.onCreate(Login.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)ode here
```

Comment: If that is the complete contents of `activity_login.xml` then it is not valid - it must have an enclosing layout tag.  Which one is part of your design of the view to be rendered.  Similar to what you have for `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: hello! sorry im a new programmer, what is an enclosing layout tag? and may i know what you mean by " which one is part of your design of the view to be rendered "?

Comment: my activity_login.xml also has
`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity">`

Answer (score 0):

this how your activity_login.xml should look like, you have to inclose the layout tag

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/signInText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
    android:text="Sign into your account!"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signInText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
    tools:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logInButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="153dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="164dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yup my activity_login.xml looks like that, turns out it was the button in activity_login.xml that caused the crash, when i removed the button in activity_login.xml the app wouldnt crash when i clicked the button in activity_main.xml. But once i had the button in activity_login.xml the app wouldnt work anymore after clicking the button in activity_main.xml. Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: you're not explaining the problem properly, so when does the app crash? when you click the button or when you build the project? and can I see the error log